# error to connect the frontend to smartContract

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I am making a react,hardhat,solidity project
but while integrating the smartContract to react using ethers js, I got some errors like
i had installed all the dependences and the react app is getting compiled succesfully

````
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.ts:285:1)
    at Fragment.fromObject (fragments.ts:456:1)
    at Fragment.from (fragments.ts:435:1)
    at interface.ts:101:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at new Interface (interface.ts:100:1)
    at getInterface (index.ts:822:1)
    at new BaseContract (index.ts:664:1)```

Please help me resolve this error
how to resolve this error
````

Answer (score 0):

Try out web3client.app

[Here](https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea) is the link to download erc20 directly and you can execute it.

It uses ethers default provider to execute the transaction. Try the code feature to get the working code you are looking for.

This might help you i believe.

Alternatively, you can try hardhat to deploy contract locally before pushing it to prod

[Here](https://youtu.be/NipAzRl4klo) is a small tutorial for it.